# Vagrant - cache RPM's for faster provision

Tags: centos, vagrant, rpm, devops

Currently have a Vagrant setup with a CentOS box with a shell provision script that installs few RPM's (via `yum install`). I'm constantly doing `vagrant destroy -f && vagrant up`, thus downloading those RPM's every time.

What's the best way to cache the downloaded RPM's and avoid downloading them on each iteration?

Answer (score 3):

Moving the `cachedir` to the shared folder `/vagrant` seems to work fine.

To change it, provision a `/etc/yum.conf` with the following edit:

```
cachedir=/vagrant/tmp/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=1
```

Now your cache is preserved outside the VM.